# Php - Foreach returning one value, first or last

Tags: php, function, foreach

If I use return in my function, I will get only one value.

If I use echo, I get all the values. I don't get it.

```
foreach($matches[0] as $matchbun)
{

        $var1 = str_split($matchbun, 34);
        $replace_line = "-";
        $var_final = str_replace($replace_line, " ", $var1[1]);

        $replace_url = array('google.com', '/name/');
        $replace_url_with = array('yahoo.com', '/url_');
        $url_final = str_replace($replace_url, $replace_url_with, $matchbun);



        return ''.ucfirst($url_final).'';

}
```

Seems that I can't insert the echoes into a database, they appear blank if I run the function.
What to do?

Comment: Sorry mates, I'm new here, didn't knew I had to mark anything. I did now, hope it's ok. Let me know.

Comment: Sorry for my bad words, but at-least something good happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a `return` the code would not execute further. Generate the whole data, then `return` that data.

You can either built an array. Like -

```
$urls= array();
foreach($matches[0] as $matchbun)
{
    .....
    $urls[]= ucfirst($url_final);
}
return $urls;
```

Or You can generate a string. Like -

```
$urls= '';
foreach($matches[0] as $matchbun)
{
    .....
    $urls.= ucfirst($url_final);
}
return $urls;
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved with: $urls= '';
foreach($matches[0] as $matchbun)
{
    .....
    $urls.= ucfirst($url_final);
}
return $urls; <3

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you use `return`, you'll exit from that function on first iteration.
If you use `echo`, you are not exiting the function, you are echoing every iteration of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Take return out of loop. and put data you want to return in a variable. Like this:

```
foreach($matches[0] as $matchbun)
  {

    $var1 = str_split($matchbun, 34);
    $replace_line = "-";
    $var_final = str_replace($replace_line, " ", $var1[1]);

    $replace_url = array('google.com', '/name/');
    $replace_url_with = array('yahoo.com', '/url_');
    $url_final = str_replace($replace_url, $replace_url_with, $matchbun);
    $myNewVariable .= $url_final;
  }

    return $myNewVariable;
```