# foreach return single result codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want a array with owen key
but when i am trying to do this it return only first result any idea?

```
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach($query->result() as $row) {
        $data = array(
         'Name'-> $row->name
        );
    }
    $users = $data;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php - Foreach returning one value, first or last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361907/php-foreach-returning-one-value-first-or-last)

Answer (score 1):

This should be like,

```
$data = array();
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach($query->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row->name;        
    }
print_r($data);
    $users = $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $data = array();
  foreach($query->result() as $row) {
        array_push($data,array(
         'Name'-> $row->name
        ));
    }
    $users = $data;
```